# How to store a DTO in thymeleaf th:value? (Spring, Java)

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, dto

I'm having this DTO with respective getters and setters.

```java
/** This class encapsulates the attributes of a JSON Schema database object. */ 
public class SchemaDto {

  /** The JSON String representation. */
  private String json;

  /** The note of the schema. */
  private String note;

  /** The date of the schema. */
  private LocalDate date;

...

  /** Returns a unique string representation of the schema. */
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")) + " - " + note;
  }
}
```

On my HTML page I want to load all schemas in the database in a `<select />` and let the user select a schema by date and note, edit the schema and process it. The date and note combined are unique.

```html
<select th:field="*{s1Schema}"
        th:onchange="|setEditorText('s1-editor', '*{s1Schema.json}')|" >
    <option th:each="schema : ${schemas}"
            th:value="${schema}"
            th:text="${schema.toString()}"></option>
</select>
```

Let me explain the code a bit more:

- `th:field="*{s1Schema}"`: Shall be of type `SchemaDto`. I want to store this in the session, so that if the schema is being processed the selection and the editor won't be lost.
- `th:each="schema : ${schemas}"` are of type `SchemaDto`, where `${schemas}` is a `List<SchemaDto>`
- `th:value="${schema}"`: I want to get the schema as a `SchemaDto` however it calls `schema.toString()` when passed to `th:field`.

I actually need all three attributes of the `SchemaDto`. The `date` and `note` are used to display the schema in the select and the `json` is supposed to be loaded to ace editor.

```js
    /**
     * Sets the editor text.
     *
     * @param id The editor's id.
     * @param text The text to set.
     */
    const setEditorText = (id, text) => {
        let editor = ace.edit(id);
        editor.setValue(text, 1);
    }
```

I would appreciate any help gladly! :)

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't know whether this is possible, I'm using Ajax now in order to avoid the reload.